# Targeting multiple layout handles in layout XML

Tags: layout

I have a custom controller accessed at the path `/custommodule/customer/info` which is loading the `2columns-left.phtml` template on the `root` node as follows:

```
<custommodule_customer_info>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</custommodule_customer_info>
```

What I would like to do is update the root template for customers who are not logged in, something such as:

```
<customer_logged_out>
    <custommodule_customer_info>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </custommodule_customer_info>
</customer_logged_out>
```

I understand that I can't target multiple layout handles in this fashion, but the intent should be clear; update the root template for this layout handle while customers are not logged in.

I had thought that I could target my controller's handle with the following:

```
<customer_logged_out>
    <reference name="custommodule_customer_info">
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_out>
```

This indeed does update the root template with the `1column.phtml` template, but it is doing so on what appears to be all pages instead of just the page targeted in my `reference` node.

I have tried several permutations of this layout update, but none seem to work. How can I target this one layout handle while at the same time using the `customer_logged_out` layout handle?

-- edit --
To be clear, this is actually a third-party module.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since you are using your own controller you don't need to only use the default handles. Based on the logged in status you could add in your infoAction method

```
 $this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addHandle('mymodule_customer_info_logged_in');
```

or

```
 $this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addHandle('mymodule_customer_info_logged_out');
```

and then in your layout.xml file use

```
<mymodule_customer_info_logged_in>
```

and

```
<mymodule_customer_info_logged_out>
```

-- addition after your edit below --

Seeing that you don't want to edit the controller (since it is a 3rd party extension), I would create a separate extension that only observes controller_action_layout_load_before

```
    $update = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getUpdate();
    $handles = $update->getHandles();

    if (in_array('custommodule_customer_info', $handles)) {

        //code to add the custom handles based on login
    }
```

Comment: Snazzy. This is not ideal, but is a relatively clean solution. As I mentioned in my other comment below, I'd rather not have to modify a third-party module, but it looks like there isn't much of a choice here. Shame, because the `customer_logged_in/out` handles **could** be so powerful, but they get gimped because of this limitation.

Answer (score 14):

Alan Storm has answered something similair like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5601579/1157493

You can use a helper to do your logic of checking whether the custom in logged in.

```
<action method="setTemplate">
    <template helper="mymodule/myhelper/switchTemplateIf"/>
</action>
```

It will call `Mage::helper('mymodule/myhelper')->switchTemplateIf();`
In that helper you can decide to switch the template or just keep it like this.

I believe it sets the template to whatever you `return` in that function.

It would look something like this:

```
public function switchTemplateIf() {
    if (Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()) {
        return 'page/1column.phtml';
    } else {
        return 'page/2column-right.phtml';
    }
}
```

Untested

Comment: I did have this thought as well, but I was hoping to only have to rely on the module's layout XML to perform this without having to rely on additional classes in the module - the philosophy of "if it can be done in XML, do it in XML, don't create additional module resources if it's not necessary".

Comment: @pspahn Of course the goal is to try and do it with the XML layout system Magento provides, unfortunately it does have its limitations and I believe this is one of them. Although I still think this is a perfectly viable solution despite the extra module resource.

Comment: @pspahn Fooman has a good alternative solution which I would recommend over mine. It requires less coding!

Comment: In this case, I'm actually dealing with a third-party module. I'd rather not have to edit their module (since updates may break it) and I'd rather not place this in a separate module's helper class (since that ties their module and module together at the hip).

Answer (score 6):

I recently needed this kind of functionality & it was getting difficult adding more & more layout handles for all the different combinations of existing layout handles, so i created a magento extension to add the ability of targeting multiple layout handles from the layout xml directly.

Here's the link to the extension-
https://github.com/mridul89/MultipleHandles.git

You would use it like this-

```
<customer_logged_out ifhandle="custommodule_customer_info">
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_out>
```

This will tell magento to only use this particular `customer_logged_out` layout handle if `custommodule_customer_info` layout handle is also present.